# How to rescue a multi-session CD?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, compact-disc, dd, ddrescue

I have a multi-session CD whose contents I want to copy to a hard drive. The CD is around 20 years old and it has several parts presenting read issues, so it is a potential candidate for `ddrescue`.

The problem is that `ddrescue` doesn't seem to recognize any sessions other than the first one in the CD, just like `dd` does. Its documentation doesn't even mention multi-session CDs and there seems to be not much information available on the internet about how to do it.

So the question is: how to rescue a multi-session CD using `ddrescue` or any similar tool?

Comment: Note: each CD session has its own ISO9660 file system. When you copy an ISO image from a CD, you are actually copying only one of those file systems (the first one, actually). You may use a tool like `cdrdao` to copy multiple sessions, but don't expect it to rescue hard-to-read data like `ddrescue` does. That's why I posted this question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you have mentioned the unfortunate answer in your comment: `ddrescue` does not know how to address individual session. I suspect this is a deliberate choice of the Linux kernel CD-ROM interface: it shows only whatever session it considers relevant. To bypass this, I believe `cdrdao` does something special which makes it possible for the tool to access individual sessions (for example with the `--session`) flag.

In my tests, the following yields one big binary file (`.bin`) and a Table of Contents (`.toc`) file describing the disk:

```
cdrdao read-cd --read-raw --datafile data.bin data.toc
```

It does not retry or check anything, so it's not quite a rescue. But it might be able to rescue mixed-mode CD-ROMs and address individual sessions. If the above does not find all sessions (you can check how many sessions are present with `cdrdao disk-info`), you can extract individual sessions with:

```
for session in 1 2 3 [...] ; do
    cdrdao read-cd --read-raw --session $session --datafile data-$session.bin data-$session.toc
done
```

The `.bin` files need to be converted to show up as `ISO` files, using [bchunk](http://he.fi/bchunk/):

```
bchunk data.bin data.toc data
```

If all goes well, this should create a `data.iso` for the relevant section of the disk. It might also create a `data.ugh` file if it fails to convert, and I do not unfortunately know how to handle that case.

Comment: I still have those old CDs, so I'll definitely try recovering them again at some point in the near future. I'll let you know if your suggestions work (and then accept your answer). Thanks!

Comment: awesome, thanks. and do let us know if you find out how to make `ddrescue` work as well! :)