# How to copy a harmed CD into an ISO on Linux?

Tags: linux, burning

I have a CD with a defective sector, and when I try to copy it with K3B it hangs there no matter what error handling configuration I chose.

Is there a way of cloning the CD into an ISO, even it having defective sectors?

Comment: If the sector is intentionally defective, as part of a copy-protection routine, it will very likely not work if you copy it, as the sector will then no longer be 'broken',

Answer (score 4):

[GNU ddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) sounds like the best tool for dealing with read errors. If you had multiple copies / disks your chances of full recovery would be greatly enhanced, but it sounds like you've only got the one.

[GNU ddrescue's manual even has a section on CD-ROMs and DVDs](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Optical-media), it's relatively short so I'll just put it all here, along with the single-disk examples:

> ### 9 Copying CD-ROMs and DVDs
>
> Ddrescue may be better than dd for copying recordable CD-ROMs because the two lead out sectors at the end of some of them may cause a read error that prevents the whole last record from being copied by dd, potentially losing data. Also dd may create an image larger than the original if the 'sync' conversion and a block size larger than the sector size are specified.
>
> In the special case of reading CD-ROMs (but not DVDs), the specialized tool dvdisaster may be a better option than ddrescue for recovering data because dvdisaster can read and analyze raw CD sectors, which ddrescue can't.
>
> Recordable CD and DVD media keep their data only for a finite time (typically for some years). After that time, data loss develops slowly with read errors growing from the outer media region towards the inside. It is a good idea to make two (or more) copies of every important CD-ROM/DVD you burn so that you can later recover them with ddrescue.
>
> If you have only one copy of a CD-ROM or DVD that fails when being copied, and if you have access to multiple optical media drives, you have a better chance of recovering the bad sectors since one drive may fail to read a particular sector, but another drive might be able to squeeze the data out of it, depending on the laser frequency and the sensitivity of the laser-sensor that reads the reflected laser light.
>
> Example 1: Rescue a CD-ROM in /dev/cdrom.
>
> ```
> ddrescue -n -b2048 /dev/cdrom cdimage mapfile
> ddrescue -d -r1 -b2048 /dev/cdrom cdimage mapfile
>  (if bad-sector size is zero, cdimage now contains a
>   complete image of the CD-ROM and you can write it
>   to a blank CD-ROM)
> ```
>
> Example 3: Rescue a CD-ROM in /dev/cdrom using two CD drives from two different computers, writing the image into an USB drive mounted on /mnt/mem.
>
> ```
> ddrescue -n -b2048 /dev/cdrom /mnt/mem/cdimage /mnt/mem/mapfile
> ddrescue -d -r1 -b2048 /dev/cdrom /mnt/mem/cdimage /mnt/mem/mapfile
>  (umount the USB drive and move both USB drive and CD-ROM to second
>     computer)
>  ddrescue -d -r1 -b2048 /dev/cdrom /mnt/mem/cdimage /mnt/mem/mapfile
>    (if bad-sector size is zero, /mnt/mem/cdimage now contains a
>     complete image of the CD-ROM and you can write it to a
>     blank CD-ROM)
> ```

FYI, here is dvdisaster's [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvdisaster) and [Debian package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/dvdisaster) pages. It sounds particularly valuable for creating recovery ECC data *before* something goes wrong.

Comment: Note: [multi-session CDs may be problematic](https://superuser.com/q/1188057/432690).

Comment: Actually that's the case, the CD is multi-session. Linux only shows the first session when mounted, and Windows show it properly. Any idea where to report this bug?